# Running CGI Scripts in Apache

Tags: windows, apache, cgi

I am using Apache 2.4.4 on Windows XP .While trying to run CGI scripts , the browser gives 
" 500 Internal Server Error" i have tried to solve after looking through various forums but no luck so far
My httpd.conf file is as follows :

```
<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:/config/apache/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
#Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

<Directory "D:/config/apache/cgi-bin/">
AllowOverride All
Options Includes ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have also looked in the error logs and this is the problem:

```
[win32:error] [pid 3824:tid 1216] [client 192.168.1.4:1728] AH02102:      D:/config/apache/cgi-bin/printenv.pl is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line
[cgi:error] [pid 3824:tid 1216] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 192.168.1.4:1728] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: D:/config/apache/cgi-bin/printenv.pl
```

Please , any help is highly Apreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess your back-end cgi consumer program is perl for your printenv.pl.

and the error is clear, apache don't know how to treat this printenv.pl file.

you need to tell apache how to interpret it by modify apache config files.

checkout mine.types

checkout this below . may be help.

[Is it possible to run a batch file as a cgi in apache under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388631/is-it-possible-to-run-a-batch-file-as-a-cgi-in-apache-under-windows/27813018#27813018)