# Is it possible to run a batch file as a cgi in apache under windows?

Tags: windows, apache, cgi

This sounds incredibly simple to do, but I can't make it work. I have it working with awk and perl, but cmd.exe wasn't designed to be a cgi program so no matter what I do, I either get the browser downloading the file, internal server error, or I get the path of the current directory as the first line.

You HAVE to put a #! in the first line of a cgi, or you get an internal server error, but I end up with

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\cgi-bin>#!c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML><BODY>
<PRE>Your environment variables are:
</PRE></BODY></HTML>
```

I've tried with /c, without, any number of permutations, it always prints the current working directory first before anything, so I can't print out the content type as a header.

Anybody ever get this working? I see lots of speculation in the results google shows me, but no actual working examples.

Answer (score 2):

1. First check Apache mine.types, comment out this line .

   `#application/x-msdownload           exe dll com bat msi`

   to

   `application/x-msdownload            exe dll com bat msi`

   This line means : Apache treat `.exe`, `.dll`, `.com`, `.bat`and `.msi` file as download file instead of executing it.
   So if you want to run `.bat` file in cgi , you need to comment it out.(I guess you have already done that, just in case somebody new doesn't know.)

   `#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .bat .ext`

   As I tried, if you left this above line commented out, it will not influence.I'm using Apache 2.2 server of Zend . So just leave it alone.
2. Write your bat file

   `#!c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c`

   This kind of shell-like comment is not working , at the first line of `.bat` or `.cmd` file, you need to write :

   ```
   @echo off

   echo Content-type: text/plain

   echo.
   ```

   The last line means output a new line , if you didn't do that, you will get "Premature end of script headers: xxx.bat " 500 HTTP error.

   `echo ^<html^>`

   "^" is escape character for cmd.

   `echo ....`

   The reason why your `.bat` not working is because that you did not stick to the HTTP protocol.
3. Put your `.bat`/`.cmd`/`.exe` file into cgi-bin directory.

   Now , check it out.
4. Advise : read the HTTP protocol.
5. Other issues:

   If you invoke other `.exe` in your cgi bat file such as [curl.exe](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) ,it will not work as expected,I don't know why , any information will be thanks.
6. Refers:http://www.jlk.net/apache/debugging_cgi.shtml

Comment: I have added this for cecurity reason:        `Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` (in directory tag)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% clear on the method you are using right now, but...

I don't think you can treat exe files (i.e., cmd.exe) as a CGI binary (e.g., `AddHandler cgi-script .exe`), nor run .bat files directly.

If you want to execute a batch file via Apache (and display the output on the page), the simplest way to do this is to execute that batch file by running a PHP script that uses `exec(path to bat file)` to execute the command line operation and echo its output.

Aside from doing this in your Browser via a URL, you can also do this from the command line by using wget/curl, or you can bypass Apache and run the PHP interpreter directly.

And I'm sure you can also do something similar to `exec()` via perl.

Comment: I have defined .bat as cgi-script for an AddHandler. I put the full path of cmd.exe in the first line of the bat file I'm trying to run. this is the traditional way unix shell scripts know what interpreter to run. Apache uses this technique in windows as well. I can use awk or perl as the command interpreter, but I can't get cmd.exe to work.

Comment: I agree it can be done by exec from php or perl and system() from awk, but I don't want to have to fork exec an interpreter just to fork exec another interpreter. I figure there's got to be a way to run the cmd.exe interpreter directly.

Comment: If the server is on a Windows OS then it can run any executable as a CGI. Long ago I wrote a simple batch file that implemented a crude comment form via CGI. The batch file accesses the CGI variables via passed environment variables. It's entirely doable. Recommended, well that's another question.